# работа с unicode в python 2.7

Tags: python, unicode

Есть фрагмент кода:

```
self.city = str(rec[18])
self.country = str(rec[19]) + ' ' + str(rec[20])
self.street = str(rec[21])
self.house = str(rec[22])
self.flat = str(rec[23])
self.corps = str(rec[24])
self.full_addr = (str(rec[33]) if rec[33] is not None else (str(rec[34]) + ' ' + str(rec[35]))) + ' ' + \
                 str(rec[36]) + ' ' + \
                 self.house + ' ' + \
                 self.flat + \
                 ' ' + \     #ошибка здесь
                 self.corps
```

`rec` - представляет собой `tuple` со всякими значениями вперемешку `int`, `unicode`, `None` - особого значения это не имеет, проблема в том, что на строке

```
' ' + \  # ошибка здесь
```

в процессе работы выскакивает ошибка:

```
File "client0.py", line 180, in initFromOtherRec
    ' ' + \
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-6: ordinal not in range(128)
```

и я решительно не понимаю в чем проблема, ведь все данные переведены в текст (причем текст одинакового формата).

Расскажите мне, где я не прав?

Comment: У Вас там скобки не хватает, добавьте в вопрос код, который идет ниже и попробуйте заменить `' '` на  '111' например, что будет?

Comment: еще попробуйте использовать `.format()`, это сделает код гораздо более читабельней: `'{house} {flat}'.format(house=self.house, flat=self.flat)`

Comment: спасибо за совет, попробую

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем, проблема была в русском тексте в rec[33], решилось это заменой

```
str(rec[33])
```

на

```
str(rec[33].encode("utf-8"))
```

И как всегда, без публикации вопроса здесь я этого, почему-то, не смог понять